# How do I trigger Franklin's Grass Roots mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've almost completed the game except for the missions "Grass Roots - Franklin" and "Grass Roots - The Pickup". Franklin's mission never triggered throughout my entire time playing.

I tried saving game in new slot, quick save, calling, going to that location ("Grass Roots - Franklin"), restarting, but nothing worked. How can I trigger this mission?

Comment: Do you mean the one where he drives the tow truck??

Comment: I think you have to cross the road from Franklin's old house and Tonya is usually there.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar tonya missions are completed left over missions are with barry and franklin. I feel like I have done Grass Roots - Franklin and Grass Roots - The Pickup. But it shows as incomplete in social club checklist. I think it is corrupted and nothing to do. Gameplay - 99/100% , strangers and freaks - 18/20.

Comment: Did you choose Deathwish when you met the Devin Weston? Or the other options? If the latter is true, (ie you killed Trevor or Michael), then it will never show 100% completion.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar I have chosen Deathwish.

Comment: Probably a bug but this would be very unusual. Glitches in the game do happen, but they are fairly innocous.